# Two-way binding not working for Nested directives - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Scenario**:

I do not want to open more than 3 chat windows on my page. Although I am able to manage that partially, what I want to achieve now is

> **to show USER buttons again if any chat window is closed** (so that the user can again open a chat window if he closes any one of three)

[Here is the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hPnQ1YlSSwkWPLYzv9k7?p=preview) . I have taken care of two-way binding

I am handling that in this link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  scope.close = function (){
       element.hide();
       alert('scope.count not reducing the actual count on  index.html')
       scope.count--; // <-- THIS IS NOT DECRESING THE COUNT on main index.html
  }  
  scope.$watch('box2', function(newIsOpenVal, oldIsOpenVal){
    if(newIsOpenVal !== oldIsOpenVal){
      element.find("#msg").toggle();
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: I see no two-way binding, but I *do* see isolated scope between two directives.

Comment: @Makoto: i have kept `count: '='` in isolated scopes

Comment: Yes, hence why I'm not seeing any two-way binding between the two.  They're effectively cut off from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in your implementation is that you are not using the `count` from your controller's scope, to solve it you should do :

```
$compile("<div chat-toggle user-name="+scope.userName+" count='count'></div>")(scope)
```